# NetData not showing the correct version after upgrade

Tags: network-manager, email-client

I installed netdata some time ago and according to official instructions if the .envoronment file is not available then you simply do a reinstall over the old one.

After I did this I get the following issues:

`/opt/netdata/bin/netdata -version Says: netdata 1.11.1_rolling`

But If I try to upgrade my system says:

`netdata is already the newest version (1.9.0+dfsg-1)`

`systemctl status netdata`

Shows:

```bsh
root@vps344333:~# systemctl status netdata
● netdata.service - netdata - Real-time performance monitoring
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/netdata.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/netdata.service.d
           └─limits.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-07-19 14:58:07 CEST; 17min ago
     Docs: man:netdata
           file:///usr/share/doc/netdata/html/index.html
           https://github.com/firehol/netdata
 Main PID: 20040 (netdata)
    Tasks: 14 (limit: 4587)
   CGroup: /system.slice/netdata.service
           ├─20040 /usr/sbin/netdata -D
           ├─20071 bash /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/netdata/plugins.d/tc-qos-helper.sh 3
           └─20075 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/netdata/plugins.d/apps.plugin 3

Jul 19 14:58:08 vps344333 netdata[20040]: 2021-07-19 14:58:08: netdata ERROR: PLUGINSD: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/netdata/plugins.d/node.d.plugin' exited wi
Jul 19 14:58:08 vps344333 netdata[20040]: 2021-07-19 14:58:08: netdata INFO : PLUGINSD: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/netdata/plugins.d/node.d.plugin' thread ex
Jul 19 14:58:38 vps344333 netdata[20040]: 2021-07-19 14:58:38: netdata INFO : PLUGINSD: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/netdata/plugins.d/charts.d.plugin' thread
Jul 19 14:58:40 vps344333 netdata[20040]: 2021-07-19 14:58:40: cgroup-name.sh: INFO: cgroup 'system.slice_lxd.socket' is called 'system.slice_lxd.socket'
Jul 19 14:58:40 vps344333 netdata[20040]: sh: 1: exec: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/netdata/plugins.d/cgroup-network: not found
Jul 19 14:58:40 vps344333 netdata[20040]: 2021-07-19 14:58:40: netdata ERROR: child pid 20270 exited with code 127. (errno 9, Bad file descriptor)
Jul 19 14:58:40 vps344333 netdata[20040]: 2021-07-19 14:58:40: cgroup-name.sh: INFO: cgroup 'system.slice_lxcfs.service' is called 'system.slice_lxcfs.servic
Jul 19 14:58:40 vps344333 netdata[20040]: 2021-07-19 14:58:40: cgroup-name.sh: INFO: cgroup 'system.slice_snapd.socket' is called 'system.slice_snapd.socket'
Jul 19 14:58:40 vps344333 netdata[20040]: sh: 1: exec: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/netdata/plugins.d/cgroup-network: not found
Jul 19 14:58:40 vps344333 netdata[20040]: 2021-07-19 14:58:40: netdata ERROR: child pid 20279 exited with code 127. (errno 9, Bad file descriptor)`
```

Any ideas how to fix this appreciated.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you installed Netdata using a package manager instead of the kickstart.sh script? If so, better remove it via the package manager and then run
bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh)